# Without changing path variable, how do I use libraries from a different folder?

Tags: windows, mingw, mingw32, path-variables

I'm trying to set up a C++ compiler with no administrator privileges on a computer running Windows 7.  Currently, I'm using minGW because changing the environment PATH variable is the only required privileged operation.  I can't change the PATH variable, but I found a workaround [here](http://kevlaichungsing.blogspot.com/2015/01/portable-mingw-on-usb-thumb-drive.html).

A batch file containing

```
path=%path%;%CD%
cmd.exe /K
```

will start a command line that has the path changed for just that window.  This lets me compile programs, but (probably because the PATH doesn't include `C:/minGW/bin`) the resulting .exe files will only run if they're in the same folder as the .dll files from `C:/minGW/bin`.

Is there any way to fix this aside from copying those libraries into the folder containing the compiled program?

Code I'm using to test the compiler:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Copying dependencies into the application folder is the default deployment. Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: Also, changing PATH doesn't require administrator privilege.  (If the user configures a PATH variable, the user variable and the system variable are combined.)

Comment: ... not that using a batch file is a *particularly* bad way of doing it, either.  Why don't you just change the first line of the batch file so that it adds both the current directory and whatever other directories you need?

Comment: When I go to Computer -> Properties, the user PATH variable is under advanced system settings, and that entire menu requires administrator privileges to access.  Also, how would I go up more than one directory at a time in a batch file?  I could list the entire address, but is there a way to just go up two or more levels from where the file is located?  Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm unfamiliar with DOS.